# HTML Center all content divs with unordered lists/lists in nav bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-lists, center

this might be a noobish question but I tried many solutions found here and online and still cant figure out.
I have a main menu bar with each item as a li within a ul.
How can I make it displayed in the center of the browser of all times?

By the way, I need to keep the javascript that displays correspondant submenu when hovered a main menu item working.

Below is the html,

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>nothing</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="final.css">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="final.js"></script>
</head>

<body>  
    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo">
            <div class="verti">
                    <a href="1.html"><img src="../Images/logo.png" width="642" height="68" border="0" /></a>            
            </div>
        </div>   

        <div id="menu">
            <div class="verti"> 
                <ul>
                    <li id="m1" class='menulist' onmouseover='mov(1);' ><a href="1.html">Main</a></li>
                    <li id="m2" class='menulist' onmouseover='mov(2);' ><a href="1.html">Intro</a></li>
                    <li id="m3" class='menulist' onmouseover='mov(3);' ><a href="1.html">Info</a></li>
                    <li id="m4" class='menulist' onmouseover='mov(4);' ><a href="1.html">Details</a></li>
                    <li id="m5" class='menulist' onmouseover='mov(5);' ><a href="1.html">Contact</a></li>
                    <li id="m6" class='menulist' onmouseover='mov(6);' ><a href="1.html">Service</a></li>
                    <li id="m7" class='menulist' onmouseover='mov(7);' ><a href="1.html">News</a></li>
                    <li id="m8" class='menulist' onmouseover='mov(8);' ><a href="1.html">About</a></li>
                    <li id="m9" class='menulist' onmouseover='mov(9);' ><a href="1.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>        

        <div id="submenu">
            <div class="verti">
                <ul>
                    <li id= "s3_1" class='s3' onmouseover='mov(3);'><a href="1.html">Real Info</a></li>
                    <li id= "s3_2" class='s3' onmouseover='mov(3);'><a href="1.html">Fake Info</a></li>
                    <li id= "s3_3" class='s3' onmouseover='mov(3);'><a href="1.html">Disinfo</a></li>
                </ul>   
                <ul>
                    <li id= "s4_1" class='s4' onmouseover='mov(4);'><a href="1.html">Poor details</a></li>
                    <li id= "s4_2" class='s4' onmouseover='mov(4);'><a href="1.html">Rich details</a></li>
                    <li id= "s4_3" class='s4' onmouseover='mov(4);'><a href="1.html">None-details</a></li>
                </ul>                
            </div>

        </div>
    </div><!--header-->     
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the CSS,

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
li {
    text-decoration: none;      
}
.verti {
}
#logo {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
#image {
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#menu {
    background-color: #65EBEB;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
#menu ul {
    width: 990px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: -35px;
}
#menu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 50px;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 90px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.currenttab a {
    color:red;
    font-weight: 1200;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.menulist a {
    text-decoration: none;  
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.menulist a:active { 
    background-color: yellow;
}
#submenu {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #F1F1F1;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top:0;
}
#submenu ul {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 0;
    width: 960px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
#submenu ul li {
    line-height: 40px;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 30px;
    display: none;  
    font-weight: bold;
}
#submenu a {
    text-decoration: none;  
    color: green;   
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight:500;
}
#submenu a:hover {
    color: red;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Below is the js used for display submenu,

```
function mov(object){           
    //reset submenu display to none
    displaynone();      

    //set selected menu styles
    ssms(object);

    //display submenu for selected menu
    displaysub(object); 
}

function displaynone(){
    var n;
    for (n = 0; n < 10; n++) {
        var s = document.getElementsByClassName("s"+n);
        for (k = 0; k < s.length; k++) {
            s[k].style.display ="none";
        }        
    }   
}

function menurestore(){
    for(m = 1; m<10; m++){
        var ml = document.getElementById("m"+m);
        ml.className = "menulist";
    }   
}

function ssms(n){   
    //reset unselected menu styles
    menurestore();  
    var y = document.getElementById("m"+n);
    y.className = "currenttab"; 
}

function displaysub(object){
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("s"+object);
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display ="inline";
    }
}
```

Thank you so much for the help.. Been struggling for days on this thing.

Comment: please add in fiddle.

Comment: Thanks guys. Just figured I could simply set a width to any div and make its margin to auto and its all set.. This really was a stupid question. Thank you all for the time.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this class to your `<ul>` tag:

```
.center-menu {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
}
```

Flexbox is new CSS properties that are not fully suported in all browsers, but is supported in a good amount of them.

To display sub-menu on hover with jQuery:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Hover Menu</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <style>
      ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .hover-menu {
        position: relative;
      }
      .hover-menu  li {
        padding: 15px;
        background-color: silver;
        color: black;
        border: 1px solid black;
        width: 100px;
      }
      .sub-menu {
        position: absolute;
        visibility: hidden;
        top: 0px;
        left: 140px;
      }
      .hover-menu li:nth-child(3) .sub-menu {
        top: 50px;
        left: 140px;
      }
      .hover-menu li:nth-child(4) .sub-menu {
        top: 100px;
        left: 140px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <ul class="hover-menu">
      <li><span>Navigation</span></li>
      <li>
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li>Link</li>
          <li>Another Link</li>
          <li>Yet Another</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="about.html">About</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li>Link</li>
          <li>Another Link</li>
          <li>Yet Another</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li>Link</li>
          <li>Another Link</li>
          <li>Yet Another</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <script src="vendors/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $('ul.hover-menu li').hover(function() {
        $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'visible');
      }, function(){
        $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. That was a neat and straight answer. Never looked it up and now I can learn a whole new chapter of stuff.

Comment: yup :) flexbox is a little tricky because the `-webkit-` prefix thing is required for all of its rules, but it is pretty nifty. I find that it works similarly to bootstrap as far as responsive positioning goes, once you start digging into the `flex-row` and `flex` properties.